# How can I define 2 search criteria in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to find the element with the class attribute `jive-wiki-body` and find it´s h1, h2 and h3 child elements and iterate over them. I am trying this:

```
$("#ivuFrm_page0ivu1").contents().find(".jive-wiki-body")[0]
                      .find("h1,h2,h3").each(function () {
  // do Work;
});
```

This is not working. How can I solve this?

Comment: are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: Why are you don't use just one selector?

Comment: There are still h1,h2 and h3 elements withing the contents() that I do not want.

Comment: Try to use `$("#ivuFrm_page0ivu1 > .jive-wiki-body h1,h2,h3")`

Comment: that does not cause errors but is not retrieving the correnct content.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `contents()` as it will return child nodes as well as text nodes. 
Also, use `:eq(0)` instead of `[0]`.

Overall, it can be reduced to

```
$("#ivuFrm_page0ivu1 .jive-wiki-body:eq(0)").find("h1,h2,h3").each(function () {
// do Work;
});
```

**Update**

> this is not working. I do need the .contents() to get the content in the iframe i think

Then use just `:eq(0)`. You cannot use `[0]` because it will return a native `DOM` element which does not have a find method.

```
$("#ivuFrm_page0ivu1").contents().find(".jive-wiki-body:eq(0)").find("h1,h2,h3").each(function () {
// do Work;
});
```

Comment: this is not working. I do need the .contents() to get the content in the iframe i think

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: "#ivuFrm_page0ivu1".contents is not a function

Comment: @HansEn, can you reproduce the problem in a fiddle?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort. The iframe content is retrived from a Jive system, therefore I cannot reproduce with a fiddle sorry.